# How to do: The first instance of an app will execute a process, second instance will kill the process later

Tags: c#

I want to create a console application that behaves as follows:

1. The first instance of the app will execute a process.
2. The second instance executed later will kill the process.

Is there a simple way to do so?

EDIT:
The second instance also terminates the first instance and itself.

EDIT 2:

More details scenario is as follows:

Assume there is no instance of my application running.
If I execute my application, the new instance will run.
The application will create a process that execute Adobe Acrobat Reader X (for example).

Later, I execute my application again just to kill the running Adobe Acrobat Reader X and of course its host (the first instance of my application).

Comment: You mean the first app starts an external application? Which process is killed when exactly? So app instance 1 (process A) starts an external application (process B), then app instance 2 (process C) which is started  manually kills process A and process B and terminates?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a mutex to do this.

```
     private static Mutex mutex = null;

     private void CheckIfRunning() {

       string strId = "291B62B2-812A-4a13-A657-BA672DD0C93B";

        bool bCreated;

        try
        {
            mutex = new Mutex(false, strId, out bCreated);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            bCreated = false;
            //Todo: Kill your process
        }

        if (!bCreated)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Resources.lbliLinkAlreadyOpen, Resources.lblError,         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't believe it has to be as the mutex is created once once per application process and you'd want to do it there - at start up of your app. It will be easy enough to test though.

Comment: That // todo is quite untrivial to do reliably.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a process with a known name. Then when the application starts you could get a list with all the processes that are running. If the process is not there you can start it, if it's already there you can kill the process and exit.

A more elegant solution would be as Max suggested to use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to communicate between the processes. For example to be sure that you don't kill another process with the same name.

Comment: Just need a confirmation. We can kill a process hosted by an application from other applications, can't we?

Comment: @xport-again very easy to find out by actually trying to do it yourself. Get the list of processes running on your machine, iterate through the list and kill the one needed using this method:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx